# Can I display merMod object with Flextable without GOF statistics and significance stars?

Tags: r, lme4, flextable

I have estimates from an `lmer` model that I want to output with the  `flextable` package. Is there any way to customize the output table so that the significance stars are not included? I would also like to output without the goodness-of-fit statistics? Is this possible.

Here is some simulation code:

```
library(simstudy)
library(lme4)
library(flextable)

d1 <- defData(varname = "b", formula = 0, variance = 1)
d2 <- defDataAdd(varname = "x", formula = "3 + b", variance = 5)

set.seed(1234)

dd <- genData(20, d1, id = "cluster")
dd <- genCluster(dd, "cluster", 50, "id")
dd <- addColumns(d2, dd)

lmerfit <- lmer(x~1 + (1|cluster), data = dd)

as_flextable(lmerfit)
```

And here is the output:

[image]

I would like it to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Looking at `flextable:::as_flextable.merMod` I don't see an obvious way to turn off the significance starts (@DavidGohel's answer tells you how to remove the significance-stars *key* but not the significance stars themselves). It would be nice if the function respected the global value of `getOption("show.signif.stars")` ...

Comment: Somehow, there may be a bug. I don't see the stars on my machine.  Thanks for the info about `show.signif.stars` that I was not aware of. I will try

Comment: it's ok now (only with the dev version for now) or with flextable `>= 0.9.3` for future readers @kgoldfeld @BenBolker

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delete_part()` and `options(show.signif.stars = FALSE)`

```
options(show.signif.stars = FALSE)
as_flextable(lmerfit) |> delete_part(part = "footer")
```

Comment: Thanks - it is working now. Now, if I could just print the fixed effects without the random effects, that would be perfect :).

Comment: You need to use broom and do whatever you want with it.